# Spark Streaming batch processing causes data drop

Tags: java, neo4j, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

From my understanding of Spark Streaming, I create a spark entry point, for continuous UDP data, using:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(10000));
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver(8060));
```

Now,
When I process this input stream using,

```
JavaDStream hash=lines.flatMap(<my-code>)
JavaPairDStream tuple= hash.mapToPair(<my-code>)
JavaPairDStream output= tuple.reduceByKey(<my-code>)
output.foreachRDD(
                new Function2<JavaPairRDD<String,ArrayList<String>>,Time,Void>(){
                    @Override
                    public Void call(
                            JavaPairRDD<String, ArrayList<String>> arg0,
                            Time arg1) throws Exception {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        new AsyncRDDActions(arg0.rdd(), null);
                        arg0.foreachPartition(
                                new VoidFunction<Iterator<Tuple2<String,ArrayList<String>>>>(){

                                    @Override
                                    public void call(
                                            Iterator<Tuple2<String, ArrayList<String>>> arg0)
                                            throws Exception {

                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("/dev/shm/Advertisement/data/")
                                                .setConfig("remote_shell_enabled", "true")
                                                .newGraphDatabase();    

                                        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
                                            while (arg0.hasNext()) {
                                                Tuple2 < String, ArrayList < String >> tuple = arg0.next();
                                                Node HMac=Neo4jOperations.getHMacFromValue(graphDb, tuple._1);
                                                boolean oldHMac=false;
                                                if (HMac!= null){
                                                    System.out.println("Alread in Database:" + tuple._1);
                                                    oldHMac=true;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    HMac=Neo4jOperations.createHMac(graphDb, tuple._1);

                                                ArrayList<String> zipcodes=tuple._2;
                                                for(String zipcode : zipcodes){
                                                    Node Zipcode=Neo4jOperations.getZipcodeFromValue(graphDb, zipcode);
                                                    if(Zipcode!=null){
                                                        System.out.println("Already in Database:" + zipcode);
                                                        if(oldHMac==true && Neo4jOperations.getRelationshipBetween(HMac, Zipcode)!=null)
                                                            Neo4jOperations.updateToCurrentTime(HMac, Zipcode);
                                                        else
                                                            Neo4jOperations.travelTo(HMac, Zipcode);
                                                    }
                                                    else{
                                                        Zipcode=Neo4jOperations.createZipcode(graphDb, zipcode);
                                                        Neo4jOperations.travelTo(HMac, Zipcode);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            tx.success();
                                        }
                                        graphDb.shutdown();
                                    }               
                        });
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

In the  section of output.foreachRDD I push the output into my Database(Neo4j). I understand this is time consuming process.

My doubt is, in this whole process, I see that not all the data is being pushed into my database but the data is dropping. I'm unable to understand exact reason for this, but my best guess is, when I'm pushing the data into database the spark stops receiving the data and making a batch from it. So, a solution would be to push it asynchronously. Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Comment: go to the Spark UI, take the 'Streaming'  tab and look at the 'processing time'. It should be < batch interval. What figures do you see there?

Comment: Could you add the `<my-code>` snippet? The issue shall be probably there.

Comment: I am running it on remote server which can't be reached from directly from a browser(I need to ssh twice). I have added the code of <my-code> section for output.foreachRDD.

Comment: you can also go to the driver node and get metrics through a REST endpoint: `<driver>:4040/metrics/json` Look for `<node-name>.<application>.lastCompletedBatch_totalDelay `

Comment: I tried to run "curl https://localhost:4040/metrics/json" but I keep getting "Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT". Sorry, if I sound stupid, this is my first time doing anything with Spark UI.

Comment: You have to do that on the node that's running the driver. Looks you're accessing the node from behind a proxy.

Comment: Thanks! I corrected my mistake but now the curl request doesn't return anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77293/discussion-between-d34th4ck3r-and-maasg).

Comment: One reason I figured out for not getting any reply on curl request may be because I'm using Spark Java API using maven to do the processing. And it's not even listening in the port 4040.

Comment: @maasg - My processing time(2-3 minutes) is huge compared to batch interval(10 sec). How can I solve this issue?